# Read xml file .findall() "trajectory"

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I trying to get values in a xml file.

Here's an exemple of my xml file:

```
<trajectories uid="171126T104028_0_0000314183_34" max_width_for_not_hidden="999.00">
    <images>
        <image shoot_id="1" key_dtn_trigger="xxxx" image_id="x">
            <point y="y" x="x" vy="x" vx="x"/>
        </image>
    </images>
    <trajectory uid="171126T104028_0_0000314183_34">
        <point y="i want this" x="and this" vy="and this as well" vx="still this"/>
    </trajectory>
</trajectories>
```

My code for the moment is:

```
tree = ET.parse("trajectories/test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for traj in tree.findall("./trajectories/trajectory"):
    y = traj.attrib('point')
    print(y)
```

I have some trouble with the tree.findall() part.

Does anyone know how to read any of these values ?

Thanks, I'd really appreciate if someone could help me

Comment: What exactly does *I have some trouble with the tree.findall() part* mean? Any error message or exception? Empty result?

Comment: Well, I'm feeling like I can't "access" to the "y", "x", "vy", etc line. I guess the problem is located in the line tree.findall(). And yes it gives me an empty result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the problem is that `point` is not an xml *attribute* but a *tag*. It's attributes are `y`, `x`, `vy` and `vx` and this is what you are trying to access as far as I understand from comments. So I believe your code should look more or less:

```
for p in tree.findall(".//trajectory/point"):
    x = p.attrib['x'] 
    y = p.attrib['y']
    vx = p.attrib['vx']
    vy = p.attrib['vy']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I really appreciate it. Sadly, it doesn't work. I tried print(x) to see any result but it gives me nothing... Any idea ?

Comment: Did `print(y)` printed anything in your version? Maybe it should be `tree.findall("./trajectory/point")` ?

Comment: Thank you so much ! It finally works with ("./trajectory/point") !! Have a nice day sir